# ElasticSearch get wrong highlights which contains many other chars

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

I want to get highlight result which just contains the tokens,but contains many other chars.

The data field "test_id":

```
"test_id": "a80a-e524ab28f5c5"
```

Search like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "_all": {
            "query": "ab5",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<span style=\"color:red\">"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</span>"
    ],
    "require_field_match": false,
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The result :

```
"highlight": {
    "test_id": ["a80a-e524<span style="color: red">ab28f5c5</span>"]
}
```

It contains "28f" and "c" which between the input tokens "ab" and last "5",what I want like this：

```
"highlight": {
    "test_id": ["a80a-e524<span style="color: red">ab</span>28f<span style="color: red">5</span>c<span style="color: red">5</span>"]
}
```

What can I do for this ? Thanks for any response.

Comment: what is the analyzer for  'test_id' ?  looks like it has [word-token-filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) in which case this is expected

Comment: @keety: I used IK Analyzer for it.